# Observable that cyclicly pushes a list of values

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

I want to create an Observable that keeps pushing a list of values every `t` seconds.

For example, given the {1, 2, 3, 4} subscribers should get this:

1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2...

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var observable = Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
            .Zip(Observable.Range(1, 4)
            .Repeat(), (_, count) => count);

        observable.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
    }
}
```

- I have worked on this example and it seems to work, but with a very nasty problem: the Main method **never ends its execution**! Why? :(
- And even worse, after some minutes, this console application throws an `OutOfMemoryException`!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this seems like a simple mis-placed `.Repeat()` to me.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var observable = Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
            .Zip(Observable.Range(1, 4), (_, count) => count)
            .Repeat();

        observable.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

        Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

This will now:

- Not block the console from finishing
- Not throw an OutOfMemoryException.

Note, no use of `.Do()`, no custom extension methods, no endless yielding of IEnumerables that block the thread ;-)

...and an alternate implementation without `Zip` so that hopefully a layman dev could read and understand (with disposal too!):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var observable = Observable
            .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
            //.Zip(Observable.Range(1, 4), (_, count) => count)
            .Select(i=>i+1)
            .Take(4)
            .Repeat();

        using (observable.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Finished!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've removed my suggested answer, as both Timothy & Lee's answers use built-in Rx functions and are far more elegant.  I will leave the explanation of the issue, though, as I believe it's useful:

Observables are expected to be push sequences, and `Zip` will queue items from the faster producing stream while it waits for a value from the second to pair with the next.  As `Obsevable.Range` returns these values as quick as the subscriber can handle, this fills all your memory and blocks the thread.

Comment: OK, that is NICE! I've replaced the variable `observable` by your observable, but the Main method never completes. Why?

Comment: Watch out, I've left the console application printing numbers for some minutes and it ends up throwing an OutOfMemoryException :( I don't underestand why.

Comment: Ah, yes. I think `Zip` will basically run a queue of items for one observable while it waits for something from the second to pair it with.  These are paired once a second, but the repeated observable will just fly and stuff the queue with enough integers from 1-4 that it'll use all your memory!  I'll come up with an alternative...

Comment: [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/issues/19) covers the problem this shows.

Comment: I'm not sure there's a magic Rx-solution here - the idea is observables are push-based and essentially we're wanting the infinite sequence to be pull-based.  I suggest you revert to the original solution of an infinite enumerable and use the timer to get the next value.

Comment: @CharlesMager There most definitely is an Rx magic solution here. See my answer. :)

Comment: @CharlesMager I think you ought to consider modifying your answer because that last code block is not good. I'm not saying it to be mean, I just want to make sure people aren't recreating things that are already built in. :)

Comment: @CharlesMager Your analysis of why the original code was having problems and running out of memory was spot on by the way. :)

Comment: @TimothyShields No offence taken.  I'd agree the solution I came up with, while it works, is pretty ugly. Who knew `Zip` had an `IEnumerable` overload? Every day a school day. I'll amend my answer just to leave the explanation of the issue.

Comment: thanks @CharlesMager, your explanation for the memory issue is spot on.

Answer (score 2):

Charles Mager's answer already addressed why your current code isn't working and suggested one way of fixing it. Here's the simplest way I can think of fixing it:

```
    var observable = Observable.Zip(
        Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)),
        Enumerable.Range(1, 4).Repeat(),
        (_, count) => count);
```

[This is just using the version of `Zip` that combines an `IObservable` and an `IEnumerable`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh244275(v=vs.103).aspx)

The `Repeat` extension method is defined as follows (same as Charles Mager's answer):

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Repeat(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    while (true)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In the System.Reactive.Concurrency namespace there are some classes and methods to help with scheduling.

The following code is a crude example of printing out the contents of an integer array every 3 seconds:

```
var numbers = new int[] { 1,2,3,4 };

var scs = new SynchronizationContextScheduler(new SynchronizationContext());
scs.SchedulePeriodic<int[]>(numbers, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), (n) => 
{
    foreach (var number in n)
    {
        Console.Write(number + " ");
    }
});

Console.ReadLine();
```

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for but I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, but I would like to get on Observable. Anyways, your code is nice to study :)